# Ajax not sending var to url php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

i am trying to send the variables to server but url does not go to the php file.. What am i doing wrong? Is it because i am not using a submit button? Here is my code..

```
    <table id="table">
    <?php for($i=0; $i<$totalbesin; $i++) { ?>
       <tr>
          <td class="td" id="<?php echo "name".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['n']?></td>
          <td class="td" id="<?php echo "kal".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['kal']?></td>
          <td class="td" id="<?php echo "pro".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['pro']?></td>
          <td class="td" id="<?php echo "kar".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['kar']?></td>
          <td class="td" id="<?php echo "yag".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['yag']?></td>
          <td class="ekle" id="yuk<?php echo $i?>">Ekle</td>
       </tr>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
    $("#yuk<?php echo $i?>").click(function() 
    {
    var name = $("#<?php echo "name".$i?>").val();
    var kal = $("#<?php echo "kal".$i?>").val();
    var pro = $("#<?php echo "pro".$i?>").val();
    var kar = $("#<?php echo "kar".$i?>").val();
    var yag = $("#<?php echo "yag".$i?>").val();
    var dataString = '&name='+ name + '&kal=' + kal + '&pro=' + pro + '&kar=' + kar + '&yag=' + yag;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dietup.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("span#sonuc").text("<?php echo $i?>");
    }
    });
    return false;
    }); });
    </script>
    <?php } ?>

    </table>
```

Comment: Nothing is being sent? or something partial is being sent?

Comment: Nothing is being sent.. It does not go to the url php.. The actions like echo's in that url also does not work.. I changed the url file with another to test and it did not go to that one either.

Comment: You write yours javascript inside php loop, and it's always redeclares ajax, that's why it is not working

Comment: I use ajax in other loops and it works there, weirdly it does not work in this one..

Comment: I have corrected yours script and added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the val() to text(); like below as"td" tags not having an value tag

```
var name = $("#<?php echo "name".$i?>").text();
var kal = $("#<?php echo "kal".$i?>").text();
var pro = $("#<?php echo "pro".$i?>").text();
var kar = $("#<?php echo "kar".$i?>").text();
var yag = $("#<?php echo "yag".$i?>").text();
```

Comment: Thank you.. That was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ajaxForm & ajaxSubmit, otherwise you need a submit button.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "dietup.php",
  data: {
    name: name,
    kal: kal,
    pro: pro
    //and so on
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
  $("span#sonuc").text("<?php echo $i?>");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you log the dataString variable?, Does it have the right data?

Comment: It's not about getting data because i tried giving data manualy like name: 4, kal: 3  but it did not work again..

Comment: What exactly do you get on server side ?, And how are you trying to get the posted data?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to set the value into your variables:

```
   var name = $("#name<?php echo$i?>").val();
    var kal = $("#kal<?php echo $i?>").val();
    var pro = $("#pro<?php echo $i?>").val();
    var kar = $("#kar<?php echo $i?>").val();
    var yag = $("#yag<?php echo $i?>").val();
```

Comment: It was like yours before, i changed it to test but did not work both ways.. :(

Answer (score 0):

In your code, as I understand, it seems that you are trying to assign values to your javscript variables using php.

There is a problem with syntax where you are assigning the values to your javscript variables.

Notice the following snippet from your code below:

```
var name = $("#<?php echo "name".$i?>").val();
var kal = $("#<?php echo "kal".$i?>").val();
var pro = $("#<?php echo "pro".$i?>").val();
var kar = $("#<?php echo "kar".$i?>").val();
var yag = $("#<?php echo "yag".$i?>").val();
```

Does anything seems not right?

Gotcha!!!! You are using double quotes to assign value in to your jquery selector and as well as for the php echo statement which is terminating your double quote.

Try using single quotes for the jquery selector and double quotes for the php echo statement as follows:

```
var name = $('#<?php echo "name".$i?>').val();
```

Comment: Yea i tried that too, but it did not work.. I think its not about the quotes. I tried to write a variable like var kar = 5 but it did not work either.. There is something wrong about going to the url: dietup.php

Comment: There is also problem with the data that you are trying to send to the server.

Using the combination of single quotes and double quotes for assigning values to variables and using the json data in post request as shown in Basel's post i.e. first answer to your post should solve problem.

If still the problem persists, try debugging with chrome's console / firefox's firebug plugin and see if the the javascript variables that you have created are assigned expected values and the ajax request that you are trying to send in the format you displayed does not throw any error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ajax parameter data must be object, not url string. If you want to send string url, add url string to url like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "dietup.php?&name='+ name + '&kal=' + kal + '&pro=' + pro + '&kar=' + kar + '&yag=' + yag;"
})
```

But it will be wrong approach

I have divided yours script into two logical components.
First: is php loop generates the html table
Second: javascript function, who's sending ajax request

```
<table id="table">
<?php for($i=0; $i<$totalbesin; $i++) { ?>
   <tr rel="<?php echo $i ?>">
      <td class="td name" id="<?php echo "name".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['n']?></td>
      <td class="td kal" id="<?php echo "kal".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['kal']?></td>
      <td class="td pro" id="<?php echo "pro".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['pro']?></td>
      <td class="td kar" id="<?php echo "kar".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['kar']?></td>
      <td class="td yag" id="<?php echo "yag".$i?>"><?php echo $besin[$i]['yag']?></td>
      <td class="ekle" id="yuk<?php echo $i?>">Ekle</td>
   </tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $(".ekle").click(function() 
    {
        var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
        var data = {
            name: parent.find('.name').val(),
            kal: parent.find('.kal').val(),
            pro: parent.find('.pro').val(),
            kar: parent.find('.kar').val(),
            yag: parent.find('.yag').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "dietup.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                 $("span#sonuc").text(parent.attr('rel'));
            }
        });

        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.. It is because it does not get data from td, i tried getelementById but it did not work either.. Then i used

```
var name = '<?php echo $besin[$i]['n']?>';
```

and put the data in var like this.. Now it works.. Thank you for your time.. It would be better if i could get the data from td but its ok for now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar script, hope this help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#yuk<?php echo $i?>").click(function(event) 
    {
        var name = $("#<?php echo "name".$i?>").text();
        var kal = $("#<?php echo "kal".$i?>").text();
        var pro = $("#<?php echo "pro".$i?>").text();
        var kar = $("#<?php echo "kar".$i?>").text();
        var yag = $("#<?php echo "yag".$i?>").text();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&kal=' + kal + '&pro=' + pro + '&kar=' + kar + '&yag=' + yag;

        //Uncomment to check the querystring
        //alert("dietup.php?"+dataString);

        $.ajax({
            url:"dietup.php?"+dataString,
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'text',
            cache:false,
            success:function(data){
                alert (data);
            },
            error:function(jxhr){
                alert('Ops, error: '.jxhr.responseText);
        }
        }); //End Ajax
    }); //End Click Function
}); //End Root Function
```

And here is the dietup.php example:

```
<?
//Get the parameters
$name = $_GET['name'];

//Do and return what you need
echo "your name is: ". $name;
```

?>